# Error while running IEDriverserver.exe on 64 bit system

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run `IEDriverServer.exe` on 64bit windows system.

The following is the output on windows command prompt on my desktop.

> D:>IEDriver.exe 
>  000000013F19C740000000013F19C7885555',
>   000000013F19C7A0', 000000013F19C7B8', 000000013F19C7D8'

What does this error mean?

However i can run the same `IEDriverServer` on the other computer.
The following is the output on windows command prompt on my desktop. (I am using the same `IEDriver.exe` file copied from the other system.)

> E:\Demo\swas\src\Configuration>IEDriver.exe 
>  Started
>   InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) 
>   2.31.0.0 
>  Listening on port 5555

Comment: try downloading 64 bit driver

Comment: Thanks it worked but what was the error?

Answer (score 1):

There are two IE drivers one is for 32 bit browser and one is for 64 bit browser. The problem can be random also on some systems because of difference in windows updates.

Downloading proper version removes the problem.